# Create a custom block type using macros

Tags: c++, gcc, avr

In avr-gcc you can something like this:

```
ATOMIC_CODE{
   cout << "Here I can do stuff that is very time sensitive\n";
}
```

Unfortunately this is a #define which uses a special gcc **atribute**, which I would like to avoid.

So a workaround is this:

```
void enableInterrupts(){ std::cout << "Interupts Enabled\n"; }
void disableInterrupts() { std::cout << "Interupts Disabled\n"; }
class Scoped{
    void (*cleanup)();
    bool incremented;
    public:
        Scoped(void (*clean)(),void (*before)()) : cleanup(clean),incremented(false){
            before();
        }
        ~Scoped(){
            cleanup();
        }
        void operator ++(){
            incremented = true;
        }
        bool operator!(){
            return !incremented;
        }

};
#define ATOMIC for (Scoped x(&enableInterrupts,&disableInterrupts); !x; ++x)

//Later in main.cpp
ATOMIC{
    /*do stuff*/
    std::cout << "This is atomic code\n";
}
```

The only problem is that it relys on the destructor getting called immediately (which I am not sure is a reliable method).

So is it guaranteed that the destructor will get called immediately or can the compiler destruct the object whenever it feels like it?

Comment: If the compiler conforms to the language standard, then it has to do what the language standard tells it to do and the program behaves the way the standard says. If the compiler does something different, then it does something different.

Comment: @KerrekSB Which is what?

Comment: You mean you're asking what the lifetime of an object is in C++?

Comment: @KerrekSB I am asking that once the block ends does the object get destroyed imediatly (so i suppose yes)

Comment: Contemplate perhaps the fact that the class template `std::lock_guard` exists.

Comment: @KerrekSB I usually don't use std classes (except cout)....But does that mean that the object is immediately destroyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed that the destructor will be called immediately.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

You're thinking about languages that do lazy mark and sweep garbage collection.  (ok, maybe you're not)

Comment: No I am not....I was only wondering when the destructor was called to a non pointer object

Comment: Automatic variables are cleaned up immediately when they go out of scope.